# How can i put the thumbnail beside the list item in Android?

Tags: android

I have this Code to Capture a image  and Display it back in ListView
onclick of the listitem i can capture image and  save  to image View, but  how can get  onlthe  left of the list  item?

```
         public class ShootList extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
  String[] listItems = {"HeadShot", "BodyShot ", "ExtraShot", "Video Take1", "Video    Take2", "Video Take3", }; 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
        ListView shot = getListView();
        shot.setOnItemClickListener(this);
         

 }
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int Position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    int P = Position;
     

    switch ( P ) {
    case 0:
        
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        break;
    case 1:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox1.setMessage("BodyShot").show();
        break;
    case 2:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox2.setMessage("ExtraShot").show();
        break;
    case 3:
        
        Intent Take1 = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(Take1, 0);
        break;
    case 4:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox4.setMessage("Take2").show();
        break;
    case 5:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox5.setMessage("Take3").show();
        break;
   
    default:
       
        break;
}
    
}
  

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      

            int i;
                 
        // if Activity was canceled, display a Toast message

         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"camera cancelled", 10000);
         toast.show();
         return;
         }

        // lets check if we are really dealing with a picture

         if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
         {
         
             Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
             Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
             //setContentView(R.layout.main);
           
             ImageView mImg;
             mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
             mImg.setImageBitmap(b);
        // save image to gallery
         String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
         MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, timestamp, timestamp);

         }
  }
```

}

[alt text http://audition800.com/1.jpg](http://audition800.com/1.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: you should always include an explanation of your question, not just code.

If you want an icon with your list item, then you need to include it in your list item's layout xml file, which will look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <ImageView 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@-id/image />
   <TextView 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@-id/text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you will need to create a custom [list adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and override the getView() method to set the image and text fields. For all your list view needs, go [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableLeft` property of a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) directly in your XML layout file.
Otherwise you can use a RelativeLayout, see [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Efficient Implementation of [Custom ListView](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/125/) with list items having a TextView and an ImageView